# Running simulation in PyQt5 - QGraphicsScene not updated until simulation ends

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, simulation

I'm building an application (mostly a simulation) that has a GUI with a main image such that when the user presses a button, this image will change every second or so and display an updated image each time (the update is actually just painting various things onto the parent image). Just to test, I have a loop that runs in my 'start simulation' slot that does all of the model changing and picture updating for 10 steps of the simulation.

The central image should therefore update 10 times. However, it only updates **one** time at the very end when the callback returns. My underlying model is updating properly at each step, and the image I see at the end is the correct image for the 10th time step.

I'm new to Qt and I'm sure the problem is something widget/update related, but I've been having no luck at all.

The callback I have registered to the start simulation button, which starts the image update process. The self is a subclass of `QMainWindow`

```
def start_simulation(self):
  self.map_view.place_initial_population(250, 250)
  for i in range(1, 10):
    self.map_view.simulation_step()
    self.map_view.update()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Relevant functions in the `map_view` class (which is a subclass of `QGraphicsView`):

```
def simulation_step(self):
  self.load_map()
  self.draw_dot()


def load_map(self):
  self.map_image = QImage("ancient_map_seed1.png")
  self.current_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.map_image)

  self.map_scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
  self.map_graphics_item = self.map_scene.addPixmap(self.current_pixmap)
  self.setScene(self.map_scene) 


def draw_dot(self):
  founder_pop = self.map_objects.populations[0]
  print("Height: +" + str(founder_pop.x)+ "; width: " + str(founder_pop.y))
  dot = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap.fromImage(self.red_dot), parent = self.map_graphics_item)
  dot.setPos(founder_pop.x, founder_pop.y)
  new_x = founder_pop.x + random.randint(-5, 5)
  new_y = founder_pop.y + random.randint(-5, 5)
  self.map_objects.populations[0].x = new_x
  self.map_objects.populations[0].y = new_y
  self.map_objects.population_matrix[new_x][new_y] = self.map_objects.population_matrix[founder_pop.x][founder_pop.y]
  self.map_objects.population_matrix[founder_pop.x][founder_pop.y] = self.map_objects.PopulatedTile()
```

There might be some no-op code in here since I've been trying any function that I think might be in some way related. I've also moved a little code into these functions for context.

Thanks all!

Comment: It sometimes helps to do `QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()` inside the loop.

Comment: Don't use sleep in Qt event loop (even with `processEvents`, it re-enters event loop code and there are situations where that causes problems). Instead, use a `QTimer` to call your simulation code once per second.

Comment: Change `time.sleep(1)` to `loop = QEventLoop()`
`QTimer.singleShot(1000, loop.quit)`
`loop.exec_()`

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Qt event processing is done synchronously. This means, while your program is inside your specific slot, it does not process events. `self.map_view.update()` will propably just push some `redraw` events to the event queue. Those events are not processed however.

Here's an old Qt article discussing various approaches to keeping a Qt application responsive during long calculations.

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html

Comment: Good article, and along with the other comments, helped solve my issue. Thanks!